# shape recognition on IOS objective-c

Tags: objective-c, ios5, xcode4, shape-recognition

what is the best library for shape recognition on IOS SDK ? is openCV working with IOS SDK ?

I want to recognize lines and squares and circles i don't need to recognize letters or numbers

Comment: just go through the below link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5738792/tutorial-for-iphone-opencv-on-shape-recognising?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tutorial for iPhone OpenCV on shape recognising](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5738792/tutorial-for-iphone-opencv-on-shape-recognising)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, OpenCV works fine with the official iOS SDK; it works best with Xcode (it is quite complicated to install it properly with a non-official toolchain, though).